# localhost is not working in chrome

Tags: eclipse, localhost, webrtc

I am working on eclipse. When I launch my application, browser opens automatically display some data. It works fine in IE and I have also tested it in other computers.It is not working chrome.. It always shows no data received.

I have tried many things like changing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227845/localhost-not-working-in-chrome-and-firefox)

Comment: what message you get? page not found?

Comment: It shows "no data received"

Comment: Do other simpler pages work?

Answer (score -1):

Try to put 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost!

Comment: Please elaborate your answer.