# Python Open a port fowarding (tunnel) using sshtunnel not working

Tags: python, ssh, portforwarding

Since I'm running on Windows Env so I cannot use any other lib to make connection to my server using ssh and open port forwarding. So i found this library: sshtunnel

What i did was:

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
ssh_address=('xx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 22),
ssh_username="admin",
ssh_password="something",
remote_bind_address=("127.0.0.1", 1088))

server.start()

print(server.local_bind_port)
```

Then in firefox, I try to connect through my sock using host = 127.0.0.1 and port 1088. But somehow i keep getting rejected by the proxy. The SSH is working properly as I can connect using putty or bitvise.

I've been trying to get in touch with the author of the lib but haven't got any reponse yet. Anyone has any idea on this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may have to bypass proxy for your local addresses for some versions of Firefox.

1. click "Options."
2. Select the "Advanced" -> "Network" tab.
3. Choose "settings" and open connection settings dialog. "Manual Proxy Config" should be selected.
4. Enter local IP addresses/hostnames you want to bypass i.e. 127.0.0.1,  and restart firefox.

See the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227845/localhost-not-working-in-chrome-and-firefox)

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks, i did as what they have instructed, check the "bypass for local" for Chrome/IE and make sure i have "127.0.0.1;localhost" in firefox setting, with the proxy set. Still get "The proxy server is refusing connections"