# Cannot connect to WSO2CEP Management Console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, console, wso2-cep

I am trying to use `WSO2CEP` Management console from Management console but am unable to access it through Chrome or Firefox.

Both keep saying that the `site can't be reached` or `unable to connect`. I have added exceptions and enabled javascript. Server is running fine in CLI.

Please help if I am missing something.

Comment: What is the URL you have used to access CEP management console?
It will be displayed in the  Terminal when CEP server has started.

Comment: its `https://myipaddress:9443/carbon`, I have replaced myipaddress with localhost, Internet Exporer is accessing but chrome and google aren't.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! 
My system is behind a proxy so this was the problem when I was accessing localhost via firefox or chrome. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227845/localhost-not-working-in-chrome-and-firefox) link to get over that problem.