# google chrome debugger in visual studio "site cannot be reached localhost refused to connect"

Tags: visual-studio, google-chrome-extension

I am currently trying to open a html file written in visual studio in google chrome browser and run Google Chromes debugging extension in visual studio

the following is the .json file and i am using the first configuration

```
 {
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost, with sourcemaps",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "url": "http://localhost:8080",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
    },
    {
        "name": "Attach to Chrome, with sourcemaps",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "attach",
        "port": 9222,
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
    }
]
```

but when it open in google chrome i recieve the error

> This site can’t be reached
>
> localhost refused to connect.

Comment: Is chrome started as `chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222`?

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue.

There is a temporary solution that is to add `"file": "${workspaceRoot}/index.html"` to the launch.json config.

This change will allow you to open your webapp in the Chrome browser, and you will be able to do debugging, break points...**however**, take into account that the browser will render your project as if it was opeining a local file, and **NOT using a webserver environment.**

Here is the launch.json config file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "file": "${workspaceRoot}/index.html"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 6):

After spending sometime with VScode debugging, I realized about the following facts:

- VScode can debug natively any .js file.
- VScode can debug .html & .js files with the help of extensions like
  "Debugger for Chrome" (you need to apply @Machavity changes for rendering it without *live-sever*.
- If you want to render your .html & .js files as it was a webserver (
  similar to as if was being served from Apache ), you will need some
  node extension like "*live-server*".

**How to debug with "Debugger for Chrome" & "live-server" extension:**

- Change the configuration options for "Chrome debugger" in the
  launch.json file, and make the parameter "url" to match the host that
  the "**live-server**" will use for rendering: for example, **localhost**.
- Open your index.html file and open the terminal, run "live-server".
  You can customize the port, host and other settings of the
  live-server from the command line.
- Start the debugger and apply your breakpoints where necessary.

**More info:**
 - [Debugger for Chrome](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome)
 - [Node live-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server)

Comment: I tried this but I keep getting "unverified breakpoint". Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: I would need more information for helping you on that. Is that a console error?

Answer (score 6):

Finded out one more option:

1. run `ng serve` in terminal
2. press `F5` in vscode to start chrome debugger

Answer (score 1):

Found this [related issue](http://emby.media/community/index.php?/topic/34140-this-site-can%E2%80%99t-be-reached-localhost-refused-to-connect-err-connection-refused/) which recommends that the port is forwarded to the proper local IP address for your server (it may have changed) and make sure the firewall rules are setup properly on the server.

Another suggested solution based from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32190881/how-to-solve-err-connection-refused-when-trying-to-connect-to-localhost-running) is changing the port number in your project.

**`Project Properties -> Web -> Servers -> Project Url`**

You can also follow this workaround from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227845/localhost-not-working-in-chrome-and-firefox/7334546#7334546):

> 1. Go to the LAN settings (in Chrome : Tools-> Options-> Under the hood -> Change Proxy setting -> LAN Setting)
> 2. There will be a checkbox for "Bypass proxy server for local address"
> 3. Tick the checkbox.
>
> On Mac/Apple: Chrome uses system preferences for localhost exclusion:
>
> 1. Go to System Preferences -> Network -> advanced -> Proxy settings
> 2. add 'localhost' at the bottom where it says: 'ignore proxy settings for these hosts and domains' (exceptions are separated by a comma)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

None of the other solutions worked (related to SO link in question), I didn't try the change hosts file solution. This solution below worked

https://www.webucator.com/blog/2016/06/launch-files-browser-visual-studio-code/

- CTRL+SHIFT+P
- CTR
- "other" → tasks.json
- Paste the following code:

`{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "Chrome",
    "windows": {
        "command": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
    },
    "args": ["${file}"]
}`

- On the index.html file or whatever file your working on, press CTRL+SHIFT+B.

**EDIT**

This solution is not the best since it requires you to refresh / rebuild all assets everytime you make a change, making it rather slow, especially when you use jquery

**EDIT EDIT**

For anyone reading this I run windows 10 and tested almost every solution I possibly could on stackoverflow but just ended up using atom + atom-live-server which pretty much took me 5 minutes to install and setup. Setup on how to do it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xg-W86U6_Ng

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, solved it by starting the server **first**, and then launch the chrome debugger.

You can't run the chrome debugger on a server that doesn't exist, or has been started.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify launch chrome configuration and add this one line at the end

```
{
"name": "no change",
"request": "no change",
"type": "no change",
"url": "no change",
"webroot": "no change",
"file": "${file}"
}
```