# WAMP - Connection to 127.0.0.1 Failed using Chrome but succeeds using IE

Tags: google-chrome, localhost, wamp, wampserver, proxy-server

On a WAMP platform, trying to connect to localhost.  At first I install WAMP and using Internet Explorer to open localhost. It worked fine. Then I try to open using Chrome. Message below appeared. Anyone?

[image]

Comment: Someone answered your question and you wrote "it work thank you".  Why didn't you click on the gray check mark to accept the answer?  Your not supposed to keep on asking brand new questions on top of the one old in the same thread or people might become unhappy with you.  Just my two cents....

Comment: I'm sorry, Im new to stackflow. I already gray check mark to accept the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Chrome, go to Settings > Show advanced settings > Network > Change Proxy setting -> enable the checkbox for "Bypass proxy server for local address".  To get to Chrome settings, click the three vertical dots to the extreme upper right of the Chrome browser window.

Solution courtesy of:  [Localhost not working in chrome and firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227845/localhost-not-working-in-chrome-and-firefox), which while not based on WAMP (but instead Visual Studio 2010), the underlying premise is the same.

Comment: it work thank you! but now when i want to login my localhost system, it show mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established ? If its in another laptop, it work just fine.

Comment: So you are using PHP7 and PHP7 no longer has the old and dangerous `mysql_` database extension. Switch to PHP5.6.x and it will work

Comment: Great to hear that it worked @FAR.  Stack Overflow works likes this - when we've answered your question please mark it as such which will verify it to others in the community.  The new statement about it showing *mysql_query():* upon login should be addressed as a new question.  Perhaps titled something along the lines of "Logging into WAMP server from localhost unexpectedly displays 'mysql_query():"

Comment: Hi; If we've answered your question please mark it as such which will verify it to others in the community; otherwise please let us know if any.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest Chrome version there is no proxy settings anymore.

I did manage to launch localhost by using chrome_proxy app instead of the chrome app. In windows10 with a normal chrome configuration it is located in the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application

Everything's been working since
I think it is one specific case. I hope it could help someone someday.

Cheers